# Is there possibility to use entire sentence as a key in i18n for play framework?

Tags: playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I have a file conf/messages.en
I would like to use entire sentence as a key, like

```
Hello my name is Vlad=Hello my name is Vlad
```

So in layouts I can do like this

```
<p>@Messages("Hello my name is Vlad")</p>
```

But he problem is

```
`=' expected but `m' found
```

I have tried to use with quotes but it does not work.

I want this because if you don't have translation for some key, then instead of 

my.name

 will be actual sentence

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your point of view, anyway it's not possible, keys must be a keys not free text (which could be default values in case of incomplete translation), eventually you can use dot separated key like:

`Hello.my.name.is.Vlad = Hello my name is Vlad`

Comment: Well, that's now what I want as the result. I thought that there may be some way to quote data. That's how I've been doing in Magento and it seems to be a better way. Anyways thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

We use a custom i18n back-end for our projects so I ended up extending the default `MessagesPlugin`. In our case, the plugin grabs the message key, does some parsing, and looks up the i18n value on our system. If there's no match for the key then it just passes it down to Play's default plugin (just in case).

Building on biesior's answer, you could have your views as you are wanting them:

```
<p>@Messages("Hello my name is Vlad")</p>
```

Your `messages` file would have the keys without spaces (or dots, underscores, whatever)

```
HellomynameisVlad=Hello my name is Vlad
```

and then have your custom messages plugin strip out the spaces (all non-alphanumeric I would imagine) from the key before passing it down to the default plugin to lookup the text. If it finds it then use that. If it doesn't find it then return the original key.

In pseudo-code (I can expand if you think you want to go this route):

```
public String get(String originalKey)
{
  // originalKey -> "Hello my name is Vlad"

  String lookupKey = removeSpaces(originalKey);
  // lookupKey -> "HellomynameisVlad"

  if (keyExists(lookupKey))
    return getMessage(lookupKey);
  else
    return originalKey;
}
```